# Why 'float:right' acts differently in this two approach?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Sorry if title is bad , No idea what to say...

Ok My question is simple but made me confused because I don't understand how it working.

**I'm using bootstrap 3 and Here's the HTML part :**

```
<div id="Shop_Row" class="row" >

     <!--  Shop Item Start-->
       <div id="Shop_Item_01" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail" >
                    <h4 class="text-center"><span class="label label-info">Nokia</span></h4>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/650x450&text=Lumia 1520" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                                <h3>Lumia 1520</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 price">
                                <h3>
                                <label>$749.00</label></h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p>32GB, 4GB Ram, 1080HD, 6.3 inches, WP 8</p>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-product"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like</a> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-product"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Buy</a></div>
                        </div>

                        <p> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     <!--  Shop Item End-->

</div>
```

**Okay now I want to make list order from Right to Left.**

**Here's First Approach :**
I add a **'shopitem'** class to `Shop_Item_01`.

```
.shopitem{
   float:right;
}
```

And it works fine.

**Second Approach :** I add a **'shoplist'** class to `Shop_Row`.

```
.shoplist div{
    float:right;
}
```

And now it works but it affect on all members of Shop_Item_01.

Why is this happening ? is there a way to avoid this in second approach ?

Comment: If you’re going to float something, it needs positioning. I’d start there, but you could also use Flexbox for this.

Comment: @Chris I know , I want to know why it acts different when I'm pointing to same div in css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS automatically adds style to all descendants if you use the descendant selector,   (space):

```css
.shoplist div {
    float:right;
}
```

To prevent this, you can use the child selector, `>`:

```css
.shoplist > div {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
.shoplist div{ float:right; }
```

means that it affect all div elements under it, not just the .shoplist
Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors) for more information.

[By the way, bootstrap 3 provide a class for floating.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-floats)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to avoid this, because it's how CSS works, it's a fundamental design within the language. The better you specify which elements you want to target and effect the narrow its effect is going to be.

In my example below, we want to only apply styling to the `.child` class. CSS does exactly what we say. And the wrapping element, `<p>` without the class isn't targeted.

But in Example 2, we choose the broader `.parent-2 p` now, ALL `<p>` are getting targeted.

If you want to avoid this from happening I would say target only the items you want to change. With a proper class structure.

```css
.child {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.parent-2 p {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}



/* additional styling */

p {
  font-family: arial;
}

.deeper-layer {
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- scenario 1 -->
<div class="parent">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <p class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pellentesque, leo id</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pellentesque, leo id</p>
  <div class="deeper-layer">
    <p class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pellentesque, leo id </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pellentesque, leo id</p>

    <p class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pellentesque, leo id</p>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pellentesque, leo id</p>

</div>

<hr>

<!-- scenario 2 -->
<div class="parent-2">
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <p class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pellentesque, leo id</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pellentesque, leo id</p>
  <div class="deeper-layer">
    <p class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pellentesque, leo id </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pellentesque, leo id</p>

    <p class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pellentesque, leo id</p>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pellentesque, leo id</p>

</div>
```